# How to click on all anchor elements on a webpage using webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am trying to browse to this url - https://gallant-meitner-86c223.netlify.com/#/, check the count of the `a[href]` links on the page, click on them and verify that the person exists

wdio.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  runner: 'local',
  specs: [
    'test/e2e/**/*.js'
  ],
  maxInstances: 10,
  capabilities: [{
    maxInstances: 5,
    browserName: 'firefox'
  }],
  logLevel: 'info',
  bail: 0,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  services: ['selenium-standalone'],
  framework: 'jasmine',
  reporters: ['spec', 'junit'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
   defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
  }
```

My Test

```
describe('Home', () => {
  it('should get count of the links and click on them and verify the person exists', async () => {
       await browser.url('/')
    const title = await browser.getTitle()
    expect(title).toBe('Force Vue Awakens')
    // This doesn't work as well
    const links = $$('#links a')
    const count = links.length
    expect(count).toBe(10)
    links.forEach((link) => {
      link.click()
      // Dont know how to verify each person after clicking the link
    })

  })
})
```

I am new to automated testing and web driverio. Any help or a fiddle will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach()` method does not work properly with functions that returns Promise. You can use for it `for ... of` construction. Also keep in mind if you use `webdriver-io` in `async` mode you should always resolve methods that returns Promise as well. Take a look at refactoring test:

```js
describe('Home', () => {
  it('should get count of the links and click on them and verify the person exists', async () => {
    await browser.url('/')
    const title = await browser.getTitle()
    expect(title).toBe('Force Vue Awakens')
    const links = await $$('#links a') //here you missed await
    const count = links.length
    expect(count).toBe(10)
    const beforeUrl = await browser.getUrl()
    for (let link of links) {
      await link.click();
      const afterUrl = await browser.getUrl()
      expect(afterUrl).not.Equal(beforeUrl) // here use your assertion library
    } 

  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Do you know how to get console errors on the browser from your test? I am trying to verify that there are no console errors in any tests? Any ideas?

Comment: Better create a new question, but in my opinion it is bad check for UI tests. You should not check it.

Comment: Thank you for that! Can you also explain why is it bad to do that?

Comment: because UI checks are expensive and can bi flaky. Checking console errors in such way is the same as use a steam-hammer to crack nuts :)